# Extracting Specific class file from EAR file in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, jar, pipe

I have an ear file which contains around 20 jar files. Now there is a specific jar file in this EAR say jar 1 which contains application class files.

Now I want a single line command in unix which can extract a particular class file from that jar (jar 1 in this case) present inside EAR.

Comment: do you just want to know if that class exists in that ear file or you want to actually extract it and put it somewhere else like a folder ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it in 2 stages:

1. Find the file you want:

   ```
   jar tvf file.ear | grep file_you_want.abc
   ```

   You will get the file you want with its path.
2. Extract it:

   ```
   jar xvf file.ear path/to/file/file.abc
   ```

Comment: Hi Yishai,

How do u do the oposite?  I mean, inject that file into jar into ear all back ?

Comment: @Batman: that should probably be a separate question.  The answer is likely to be some variant on `jar -uvf file.ear path/to/file/to/add.class` or something similar.  Using `jar --help` is likely to give you guidance.